# How to Show that Linear transformation is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T_1,T_2$ be two linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\{x_1,\cdots , x_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $T_1x_i \neq 0$ for every $i=1,2,\cdots, n$ and that $x_i \bot \ker T_2$ for every $i=1,2,\cdots, n$.
Which of the following is/are necessarily true?

- $T_1$ is invertible.
- $T_2$ is invertible.
- both $T_1,T_2$ are invertible.
- neither $T_1$ nor $T_2$ is invertible.

**My Approch:**

Given dimension of $\mathbb{R}=n$ and

$x_i\perp Ker(T_2)$

So, $\text{Ker}T_2=0$

Row space and null space are perpendicular to each other.

From Rank Nullity Theorem:

let T : V → W be a linear map. Then the rank of T is the dimension of the image of T and the nullity of T is the dimension of the kernel of T, so we have

$\text{dim}(\text{Im}(T))+ \text{dim}(\text{Ker}(T))=\text{dim}(V)$

Applying above result we get,

$\text{dim}(\text{Im}(T))+ 0=n$

Therefore, $T_2$ is one-one.

I could not solve this problem completely. what to do next?

Comment: Is that $m$ actually an $n$? Because for $n \neq m$, invertibility cannot occur.

Comment: m is dimension of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @Crostul The OP does *not* assume that the target space is the same as the source space.

Comment: @Crostul This question was asked in the CSIR NET examination and In the answer key, option 2 was marked as the correct choice.

Comment: I can't see how option (2) was marked as true. *If* it were given $\;m=n\;$ then yes, as in finite dimension, an operator is injective if and only if it is surjective if and only if it is an isomorphism. The map $\;T_2:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2\;$ defined by $\;Tx=(x,0)^t\;$ is injective, yet $\;T_2\;$ can't possibly be invertible as it isn't surjective.

Comment: Yes, I think answer key was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Learner, if you meant CSIR NET December 2013 question, no, the key is not wrong. It asks for m=n. The original question can be found here: [Is Linear transformations $T_1,T_2:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$
Invertible?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618531)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the options are necessarily true.

$T_1$ and $T_2$ *can* both be invertible, for example if $n=m$ and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both the identity map.

On the other hand, both $T_1$ and $T_2$ can *fail* to be invertible, for example if $n=1$, $m=2$ and $T_1(x)=(x,0)$ and $T_2(x)=(x,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $T_2$ is injective (although rank nullity is overkill: just note that $T_2(a)=T_2(b)$ implies $T_2(a-b)=0$, so if $ker(T_2)$ is trivial then $T_2$ is injective). However, it might not be onto (hence not invertible): what if $m>n$?

For $T_1$, make it a bit simpler: what are some linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$? For example, let $\{e_1, e_2\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let's say we're only looking at linear transformations which send each $e_i$ to either $0$ or $1$ - how many such linear transformations are there? Does one of them in particular seem relevant?

Comment: I have shown that $T_2$ is one-one. How to show that It's onto.

Comment: @Learner Whoops, it's late and I mistook "invertible" for "injective".